# How do I return the value of a function that Unirest and send that using Express?

Tags: javascript, json, express, unirest

I'm working on Language Translation app for my coding bootcamp. I am using the [Microsoft Text Translations API](https://rapidapi.com/microsoft-azure/api/microsoft-text-translation) on the backend to translate user input to get the desired output for each query.

I'm running into the problem that that the Function that I wrote and is not returning the data back to the front end side [(Screenshot of inspector)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCokn.png) even though the function is running correctly in the back end side [(Screenshot of Terminal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKzHv.png).

Here is currently the conversion code:

```js
function langTranslateJSON(startLang, endLang, textString) {
  let queryURL = `https://microsoft-azure-translation-v1.p.rapidapi.com/translate?from=${startLang}&to=${endLang}&text=${textString}`;
  unirest
    .get(queryURL)
    .header(
      "X-RapidAPI-Key",
      API_KEY
    )
    .end(result => {
    //data comes back as an XML string //
      let xmlString = result.body 
      
      parseString(xmlString, function (err, data) {
        console.log(data)
        return data
      })
    })
}
```

And here is the POST route to user

```js
 //Using Express//
 
 app.post("/api/Translate", function (req, res) {
    res.send(langTranslate.langTranslateJSON(
      req.body.translateFromLanguage,
      req.body.translateToLanguage,
      req.body.translateFrom));
  });
```

Comment: You should be passing a callback function so after you are parsing the string instead of returning data you need to return the data into a callback. This appears to be async issue

Comment: So where would the put the callback function in this case? @jremi

Comment: In your langTranslateJSON add forth argument called callback .... change return(data) to callback(data) .... in your post route remove res.send and only call the Langtranslate function but pass the forth argument the callback function function(data){res.send(data)}

Comment: Basically you need to have your language translate function fire and invoke the callback function that you were passing into it and once that is called you are taking the results which is the return to data and you are then sending that back via express

Comment: So when I'm passing in my parameters on the post route add a callback and then do what with it?

Comment: I will be back in front of a computer shortly and I will send you the updated code

Comment: Ok thank you much appreciated

Comment: Just posted an answer, hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// notice 4th callback argument after textString argument
function langTranslateJSON(startLang, endLang, textString, callback) {
  let queryURL = `https://microsoft-azure-translation-v1.p.rapidapi.com/translate?from=${startLang}&to=${endLang}&text=${textString}`;
  unirest
    .get(queryURL)
    .header(
      "X-RapidAPI-Key",
      API_KEY
    )
    .end(result => {
    //data comes back as an XML string //
      let xmlString = result.body 

      parseString(xmlString, function (err, data) {
        console.log(data)
        // Fire the callback here and pass in the data result
        callback(data);
      })
    })
}
```

Now inside your express POST route you need to pass in the callback function

```
 app.post("/api/Translate", function (req, res) {
  // first you call your langTraslateJSON method
  // notice the 4th argument is now passing in the callback function
  // when your method is run it will invoke the callback you are passing here
  // and pass the data to the callback. 
  // It will then invoke the Express res.send method with this data  
  langTranslate.langTranslateJSON(
      req.body.translateFromLanguage,
      req.body.translateToLanguage,
      req.body.translateFrom, function(myDataResponse){
         res.send(myDataResponse)
      })
  });
```

Comment: Glad it helped . Please mark my answer as the solution.